# Check whether directory is a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm looking for a way to test whether a directory is a virtualenv or not, e.g. by checking the existence or contents of key files inside the directory.

The purpose of this is that I want to create a script which manages virtualenvs for me and I want to prevent it from removing a directory which is not actually a virtualenv (which could e.g. happen if I used tab completion to choose the virtualenv and was trigger-happy).

Is there some standard way to detect whether a directory has been initialized as a virtualenv by `virtualenv`? I'm ok with a solution which only works with the newest versions of virtualenv.

My current solution is the check for the existence of the two paths `bin/python` and `bin/activate`.

Comment: If you keep your virtualenvs in `~/.virtualenvs/` then you don't really have to worry about that.

Comment: Why don't you just install `virtualenvwrapper`? You can try `rmvirtualenv foo`, which will remove `foo` if it's a virtualenv and won't if it's not. @WayneWerner 's way is the standard way, though.

Comment: @WayneWerner I have a lot of project going on at the same time, thus I want to keep my virtualenvs in the same directory as the project.

Comment: @erip With the script I'm creating, I try to move away from the notion of activating a virtualenv in an already running shell and I instead want to launch a new shell (to get a clean environment and to make deactivation reliable by exiting the shell). I've looked at `virtualenvwrapper` and it takes the opposite approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Check for the presence of a `pyvenv.cfg` file.

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) says:

> Running [the venv command] creates the target directory (creating any parent directories that don’t exist already) and places a `pyvenv.cfg` file in it with a home key pointing to the Python installation from which the command was run

This seems to be valid from Python 3.5.9 to at least 3.13.

Note that the proposed solution of checking for `bin/python` and `bin/activate` does not work on Windows, where you would have to check for `Scripts` instead of `bin`.

Comment: Thanks! With today's Python, that seems to be a good approach.